# How to remove randomly generated attribute from the DOM using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, attributes

Say that I know the classname of a specific element. But, I do not know a specific attribute name because it is randomized and changes on each page load.

For example:

```
<div class="myclass" lskdjf=""></div>
```

In this case, I would want to remove the attribute `lskdjf`.

If I knew the attribute, I could use something like this:

```
$('.myclass').removeAttr('lskdjf');
```

However, since I don't know the attribute name, I need another way to remove this since I cannot list the infinite number of possible strings.

There is only one other thing about this attribute which is always consistent:

- the attribute is always empty (could I remove all empty attributes without knowing the attribute name?)

How can I use jQuery to remove these random attributes from the DOM?

---

*Note: One other possibility might be to strip ALL attributes, then try to immediately add back in the attributes I wanted to keep (like the class). I don't know if this would work but it's worth a try if possible.*

Comment: Can I ask quickly, why do you need to remove the attribute if it's always empty? Also, what is generating it?

Comment: It may be time to look into using the native DOM methods, like [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes). You could either get the last attribute through that interface or use a whitelist of known attribute names and remove the ones not in the whitelist.

Comment: @BrettEast It is generated from outside. I need to remove it for my specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a big library like jQuery just for this. All you need to do is extract the element's `attributes` property, then access `attributes[attributes.length - 1].name` and remove the attribute. Here's an example of an element that gets a randomly named attribute added to it, which is then removed afterwards:

```js
const div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
div.className = 'myclass';
div.setAttribute(
  'rand' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
  'randomattributevalue'
);
console.log(div.outerHTML);
const { attributes } = div;
const attributeName = attributes[attributes.length - 1].name;
div.removeAttribute(attributeName);
console.log(div.outerHTML);
```

Or, with a pre-defined element:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.myclass');
const { attributes } = div;
const attributeName = attributes[attributes.length - 1].name;
div.removeAttribute(attributeName);
console.log(div.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="myclass" lskdjf=""></div>
```

Comment: How reliable is removing the last index @CertainPerformance? I ask because the docs say this "It is a NamedNodeMap, not an Array, so it has no Array methods and the Attr nodes' indexes may differ among browsers." - The differing indexes is why I'm asking. Cheers

Comment: jquery is already running, so it isn't extra, plus, i prefer jquery which is cleaner but will also consider your suggestion but still hoping for a jquery answer. EDIT: Just looked, are you trying to generate a string? I don't think you understood the question. The string is already generated. I am trying to remove it without knowing what the string is.

Comment: @asegfvawer You said in your question that the attribute was randomly generated, so I had the example imitate that, to show that a randomly generated attribute could be removed via the `attributes` property. Look at the code - the part that removes the attribute does not depend on knowing the attribute's name.

Comment: ok so i can just remove that part of the code? Which part of this code is relevant? Can you remove the parts which aren't part of the code used?

Comment: The idea is the same no matter what - just select the element, get its `attributes`, get the name of the last attribute, and call `removeAttribute`.

Comment: You want to get its attributes, but it has more than one attribute. After looking at your code, how will this remove only the attribute which is named randomly?

Comment: @asegfvawer That's why, as the answer says, you should access `[attributes.length - 1]` - that'll give you the last attribute, and then you can remove it. Press "Run code snippet" to see for yourself.

Comment: Last? Why last? I need to remove a random string and it is not always last.

Comment: It looks like you changed the parameters of the question after people had answered. You originally said *the attribute is always the last attribute in the div (could I remove only the last attribute?)*. Please do not ask [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can do something like this:

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0];

const attrs = element.attributes;

let emptyAttrs = [];

for(let i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
  if (attrs[i].value === "") {
    emptyAttrs.push(attrs[i].name)
  }
}

emptyAttrs.forEach((attributeName) => element.removeAttribute(attributeName));
```

This should get all the attributes and store the ones with an empty string as a value into an array called `emptyAttrs` and then loop through each of them and remove them from the original element.

Note: this may need tweaking, as I wrote it directly into stackoverflow and didn't check for spelling, edge cases etc.

Comment: I tried it, and it worked but only when the string is the last attribute. I just saw that the string where it is not the last attribute, this doesn't work.